# How to break a word using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a website and I need to break a word after "_".

For example, I have this "word":

```
test_test_test_test
```

And I want to break like this:

```
test_
test_
test_
test_
```

Is that possible?

Thanks.

I tried this, but didn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var str = $('p').text();
                var str_list = str.split("_");


                for (var i = 0; i < str_list.length; i++) {
                $('p').text(str_list[i] + "_");             
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>

<body>


    <p>test_test_test_test</p>

    <p>test2_test2_test2_test2</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is there a `_` after the last word in the result?

Comment: I'm doing this to my friend and he doesn't want to separate the words, it's kind a pattern he uses...

Comment: It does work, but you are not processing the `p` elements correctly. You are essentially setting the content of all `p` elements to the last "word" of the first `p` element. That has nothing to do with your original question though.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for split.

```
var str = "test_test_test_test";
var str_list = str.split("_");
alert(str_list[0]);
```

If you want to print all of them then you need to iterate over the list.

```
for (var i = 0; i < str_list.length; i++) {
    // I append the underscore to the end.  Remove that bit if you don't want an underscore
    alert(str_list[i] + "_");
}
```

Comment: @MaunoV. You're right.  Thats a typo on my part.  Thanks for calling it out!

Answer (score 2):

```
'test_test_test_test'.match(/([a-z0-9]+_?)/gi)
```

the result is:

```
["test_", "test_", "test_", "test"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str ="test_test_test_test";
var parts=str.split('_');
parts.forEach(function(part){
     alert(part+'_');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it:

```
var words = word.replace(/_/g '_\0').split('\0');
```

The idea is to insert a marker after each `_` and split on it. The marker should be a character that is not expected to appear in the actual data.